# Saving a Dictionary of key-values in Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question is a follow up from: [Post Array to firebase Database in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624313/post-array-to-firebase-database-in-swift/40640639?noredirect=1#comment75447263_40640639)

I am trying to save some `ingredients` into a `recipe` and later be able to retrieve the entire recipe with the ingredients inside it. After looking at the question above and this blog post https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html. I was able to re-structure my database

This is my Ingredient Dictionary:

```
{
  "IngredientDict": {
    "-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w": "Eggs",
    "-KkbWvaa5DT1PY7q7jIs": "Spaghetti",
    "-KkbaDQ8wYJxR3O2OwKd": "Parmesan"

      // More possible ingredients

  }
}
```

This is my Ingredient Data:

```
{
  "IngredientData": {
    "ingredients": {
      "-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w": {
        "name": "Eggs",
        "uid": "-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w"
      },
      "-KkbWvaa5DT1PY7q7jIs": {
        "name": "Spaghetti",
        "uid": "-KkbWvaa5DT1PY7q7jIs"
      },
      "-KkbaDQ8wYJxR3O2OwKd": {
        "name": "Parmesan",
        "uid": "-KkY90e7dAgefc8zH3_F"

      // More possible ingredients

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I now want to add these set of ingredients to my recipe in one action. This is how I currently make a recipe:

```
@IBAction func addRecipe(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let itemNameText = recipeName.text else { return }

        guard itemNameText.characters.count > 0 else {

            print("Complete all fields")
            return
        }

        let recipeKey = databaseRef.child("RecipeData").child("recipe").childByAutoId().key
        let recipeItem: [String : Any] = ["recipeName" : itemNameText, "recipeID" : recipeKey]
        let recipe = ["\(recipeKey)" : recipeItem]

        databaseRef.child("RecipeData").child("recipe").updateChildValues(recipe)

        print("\(itemNameText) was added")
    }
```

This is the outcome:

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "recipe": {
      "-Kkv36b_aPl7HAO_VYaJ": {
        "recipeName": "Spaghetti Carbonara",
        "recipeID": "-Kkv36b_aPl7HAO_VYaJ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I add the ingredients? At the moment I can manually add it on the Firebase. But I would like to be able have an action that saves the entire recipe with the ingredients. Most examples give a dictionary with a set of declared properties. However mine can be random as each recipe can have random number of ingredients.

Comment: you want to store ingredients along with recipe, in one-go, right?        In this query, databaseRef.child("RecipeData").child("recipe").updateChildValues(recipe)

Comment: Correct, at the moment that only stores a recipe. I am not sure how to store the ingredients.

Comment: Is  "IngredientData": {
    "ingredients": {  __data__ } } already there on Firebase ?

Comment: Yes, would it be helpful  to show you how I create this?

Comment: A few things: First is the key is being stored twice in the ingredients node - once as a key and once in a child node. That's probably unnecessary, just store is at key: ingredient name. Second thing, and this is a design choice, is uid generally means user id. Ingredients are not users so for readability you may want to use something other than *uid*, perhaps recipeId. But again that may be a mute point if you simplify and store each ingredient as a key: ingredient name pair. Last thing is that Ingredients->ingredients is too deep. Just store your ingredients directly in the Ingredients node.

Comment: @Jay I absolutely understand. Sorry I have been following some demo's online and they stored the key in 2 places which I agree is unnecessary. And yes I will take that into consideration in regards to how I name my uid for readability purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addRecipe` function, try this:

```
...
let ingredients: [String] = ...
var ingredientsJSON = [String: Bool]()
for key in ingredients {
    ingredientsJSON[key] = true
}
let recipeJSON: [String : Any] = [
    "recipeName" : itemNameText,
    "recipeID" : recipeKey,
    "ingredients": ingredientsJSON
]
let recipe = ["\(recipeKey)" : recipeJSON]
databaseRef.child("RecipeData").child("recipe").updateChildValues(recipe)
...
```

Comment: At the moment the `ingredientText` is just a string from a textField outlet. So it's actually unnecessary. I will update my question an remove that. How do I now store a dictionary of ingredients in my recipe?

Comment: I think the best solution is to manually add the ingredients into the recipe like `"-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w" : true`. Then do you know how I'd get the name of `-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. I can show you how I add them manually into the recipe. But at the moment my addRecipe function doesn't have anything to do with my ingredients .

Comment: The ingredients variable is inside the Recipe class

Comment: Sorry, am I not explaining clearly enough. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Ok, this works! So you're suggesting I add each _ingredient_ like this `"Chicken" : true`? But then when I want to add the entire _recipe_ (including the dictionary of ingredients) to something like a users `favouriteList`, how do I do that?

Comment: @Chace When adding a **reference** to a recipe stored in `"RecipeData"` node you should only store the **recipe's key** instead (and not copy the entire recipe data again). To retrieve the recipe data, use the `observeSingleEvent` method.

Comment: @Chace ...and don't store the ingredient name (`"Eggs"`) in the recipe; store the ingredient key instead (`"-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w"`). This might help you down the road...

Comment: I see, so how do I achieve an autoID on each ingredient so that it returns `"-KkbWdomTYdpgEDLjC9w" : true` ? Your code only instructs how to add get an array of strings into a dictionary.

Comment: @Chace Sorry, but SO isn't designed to work this way... I recommend you upvote/accept my answer as is and post another question with a **specific issue**. You will get faster/better answers that way ;)

Comment: I understand, I'm just not sure how your example has helped me now that each _ingredients_ need a key. Would this key come from the `IngredientDict`? Don't worry if this out of question, Thanks for you help anyways :)

Comment: @Chace Yes, the keys in your `IngredientDict` node! Or, if you design your ingredients names as unique/fixed, you can use the name instead (and use that as well in your `IngredientDict` children; that is, no more keys there as well).

Comment: I am getting error:  Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '/' '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'